# Unable to to view power statistics box in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, power-management

power statistics box cannot be viewed the second time it is tried to open. The box just shows blank.It doesn't appear even if left open for sometime.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like launchpad bug [#951827](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/951827), which has had a patch for the last 3 months but doesn't seem to have made it into an update yet.  As noted in comment #2, when it gets in this state you can workaround the problem by killing gnome-power-statistics from the command line:

```
kill `pidof gnome-power-statistics`
```